# Question about particular proof of the translation invariance of the Lebesgue outer measure.

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about the proof of the translation invariance of the Lebesgue outer measure that appears here: http://mathonline.wikidot.com/translation-invariance-of-the-lebesgue-outer-measure

[image]

I don't understand how equation (*) follows. I also don't understand how equation (**) follows, but if I figured out the first one, I think I would understand it.

I agree with equation (1) that $m^*(E+a) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)$. I also think that from the definition of the outer measure, we have that $m^*(E) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty l(I_n)$. But how are they concluding that
$$ m^*(E+a) \leq m^*(E)$$ from this information? I think I'm missing something simple, but I've spent several hours thinking about it and can't work it out exactly.

Comment: $\textbf{Hint:}$ if $E \subset \cup_n (a_n,b_n)$ then for any $x\in \Bbb{R}$, one has $E+x \subset \cup_n (a_n+x,b_n+x)$ and note if $l$ denotes length then $l((a,b))=l((a+x,b+x))$ for every $a,b,x$. I think this method is more clear and digestible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general property of $[0,\infty]$.

If $x \leq a$ for all $a \in A$, then $x \leq \inf A$.

This can be seen by contrapositive. If $x \geq \mathrm{inf A}$, then there exists some $a \in A$ so that $x \geq a$, else $x$ would be a lower bound which contradicts the definition of $\mathrm{inf} A$.

For measurable sets, we can restrict the [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) which is the inf of the sum of lengths for sequences of open covers.

Comment: OK so I think I got it: So translated into my question, we have $m^*(E+a) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_n)$, for all of the $\sum I_n$, and this plays the role of $x \leq a$ in your answer. Then this means that $m^*(E+a) \leq \inf\{\sum l(I_n)\} = m^*(E)$ where the last equality follows from the definition of the outer measure.

Comment: yeah, that looks right (barring some notational difficulties. What is $\sum I_n$?)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

If (*) would not be true, or equivalently if $m^*(E)<m^*(E+a)$ then covering intervals $I_n$ must exist with: $$m^*(E)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l(I_n)<m^*(E+a)$$ contradicting the former bullet.